# Maven site-deploy to nexus with webdav

Tags: maven, nexus, webdav

I fail to deploy the site to Nexus. I already have my `<server>` with username/password setup in maven settings, but it still couldn't get the credentials, and wonder why connecting to port 80 instead of my Nexus port 8081.

```
[DEBUG]  configureWagon 
[DEBUG] configureWagon server nexus
[DEBUG] configureWagon server nexus-admin
[DEBUG] repository protocol dav
[DEBUG] found dav protocol so transform to real transport protocol http
[DEBUG] getProxy 'protocol': http no ProxyInfo found
[DEBUG] Mapped url: dav:http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/sites/site/ to relative path: 
[DEBUG] authenticationInfo with id 'nexus-admin': admin
[DEBUG] connect with authenticationInfo and without proxyInfo
[DEBUG] Set parameter http.protocol.cookie-policy = compatibility
http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/sites/site/ - Session: Opened  
[INFO] Pushing C:\work\MavenWork\projectA\target\site
[INFO]    >>> to http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/sites/site/./
[DEBUG] Set parameter http.authentication.preemptive = true
[DEBUG] Set parameter http.socket.timeout = 60000
[DEBUG] HttpConnectionManager.getConnection:  config = HostConfiguration[host=http://localhost], timeout = 0
[DEBUG] Allocating new connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=http://localhost]
[DEBUG] Preemptively sending default basic credentials
[DEBUG] Authenticating with BASIC <any realm>@localhost:80
[WARNING] Required credentials not available for BASIC <any realm>@localhost:80
[WARNING] Preemptive authentication requested but no default credentials available
[DEBUG] Open connection to localhost:80
[DEBUG] Closing the connection.
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[DEBUG] Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:286)
```

Below is my POM distributionManagement:

```
<distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>nexus-admin</id>
            <url>dav:http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/sites/site/</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>
```

FYI, I'm using wagon-webdav-jackrabbit version 2.10

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

This is my servers credentials from Maven settings.xml:

```
<server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>deploy</username>
            <password>deploy</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>nexus-admin</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>
```

Comment: Check your distributionManagement settings in your pom file:  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html#Deploying_the_Site

Comment: I already update my distributionManagement in the question. From the log file debug, there is authenticationInfo with id 'nexus-admin'

Comment: Are you using Nexus 2 or Nexus 3? It looks like you are using Nexus 2, just want to be sure.

Comment: I'm using Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.0-01

Comment: did you create a site repository in nexus?